# Will std::list alter the position in memory of elements?

Tags: c++

If I grab a reference to an element in a std::list via a pointer, will that pointer remain valid so long as the element is not deleted, or would I have to traverse the list each time I want to access said element?

Basically does std::list move elements around when other elements are added or removed?

I suspect not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/), the `insert()` method has no effect on the validity of iterators, and the [`remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/) method only affects the validity of the removed elements' iterators.  I suspect you want to keep around [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) pointing to the elements in the list, rather than pointers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the advantage of keeping itterators around over pointers? I'm guessing the itterators are aware of weather or not they are still valid?

Comment: No, it's just the natural way of holding "references" to particular elements in an STL container.  It's better practice to use iterators; one reason would be that they can be used by the STL algorithms.

Comment: @CodySmith Another reason is that your pointer is useless for anything other than simply getting at the element itself. For example, you can't use it to insert new elements before or after, or traversing the list from that point, etc. You're also breaking encapsulation by keeping a pointer to something which is an internal implementation detail of the list.

Answer (score 4):

References, and by extension, pointers, to elements in a `std::list` remain valid through most operations, except for removal from the container.  In fact, they can even be moved to another list, via the merge, splice and swap member functions, and they still remain valid.

Comment: Does the standard make this guarantee for raw pointers as well as iterators?

Comment: @JBentley: It makes the guarantee for references.  And if references aren't invalidated, I can't imagine how pointers possibly could be.