# Does std::list guarantee that items will never be moved to a different memory location?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Is it guaranteed that once `std::list` or `std::forward_list` item is allocated, it will remain at the same memory location (address) until destroyed? Except, of course, for the list itself being copied.

Comment: If it could move, wouldn't that invalidate all pointers against it?  That doesn't sound like it could happen.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: my point exactly. I want to know if it's safe to store direct pointer to nodes, as opposed to always accessing the items via `std::list` interface.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16027044/3549027) confirms that `insert` and `remove` will not invalidate iterators, but that is not quite a full answer to the question, IMO...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for all the functions which don't destroy elements, ([insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert), [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace), [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back), etc...), you will see that they have a note that *"no references are invalidated"*, which is equivalent to what you are asking (objects staying at the same memory location). So, yes.